# <span style="font-weight: 100 !important;"> does not have any effect on the UI

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

I am using IE 11 and I do have the following HTML:

```
<tr bgcolor="#eeeeee" bordercolor="#000000" valign="top">
        <td bordercolor="#eeeeee" align="right" valign="top">.....:<br/>
                <span style="font-weight: 100 !important;">Deaktiviert, weil nicht mehr notwendig</span>
        </td>
</tr>
```

However, in the browser, the following table is shown:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

As you may notice, the text "Deaktiviert, weil nicht mehr notwendig" looks exactly the same way as the text in the screenshot", altough I have the declaration

```
<span style="font-weight: 100 !important;">
```

before it.

Could you tell me what the problem is?

Thank you and kind regards,
Alex

Comment: Sometimes it can be font issue. If font doesn't provide that weight it just renders normal. Did you try other elements with that font?

Comment: Does the font you're using support a `100` font-weight?

Comment: I have also tried  <span style="font-weight: lighter !important;">, but the same problem.

Comment: if you are using google fonts you can do smth like `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;300;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> `

Comment: The inline style is correct, so this must be caused by the font you are using. Are you including a direct link to Google fonts or are you using font-face? Not all fonts support a weight of 100, if this is the case you might want to try 300, which is usually the chosen weight for a light version.

Comment: Hi @AlexMi May I know whether your issue has been solved or not? Are the answers below helpful to deal with the issue? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 2):

Use these links in your `head-part` (`font-weight: 100,300,400 and 500 are selected here`):

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

#one {
  font-weight: 100;
}

#two {
  font-weight: 300;
}

#three {
  font-weight: 400;
}

#four {
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    
<span id="one">100</span>
<span id="two">300</span>
<span id="three">400</span>
<span id="four">500</span>
```

Comment: This did not help me, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work with `font-weight: 100` because the font you use doesn't have that exact weight.

According to [this doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight#fallback_weights): *If the exact weight given is unavailable, then it follows the **Fallback weights** rule.* The rule means if a font only has `normal` and `bold`, when the weight value is 100-500, `normal` will be used for actual rendering, and when the weight value is 600-900, `bold` will be used for actual rendering. I think that's the situation you meet.

If you want to make `font-weight: 100` work, you need to use a font which has this weight value, for example, google fonts **Roboto**. You can use it like below, it works well in IE:

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<table>
  <tr bgcolor="#eeeeee" bordercolor="#000000" valign="top">
    <td bordercolor="#eeeeee" align="right" valign="top">
      Blitz-/Sturm-Anbieter:<br />
      <span style="font-weight: 100 !important;">Deaktiviert, weil nicht mehr notwendig</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```